# How to load texture into openGl using png++?

Tags: c++, opengl, libpng

This line will read the texture into memory and store it in an image:

```
png::image<png::rgba_pixel> image("texture.png");
```

This line should then load it into openGL memory:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image.get_width(), image.get_height(), 0, GL_ABGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.get_pixbuf());
```

However, the last argument should be `const void*`, but `image.get_pixbuf()` returns `pixbuf`. How do I get the pixel data from image into openGL?

Ignore any other arguments I specified wrongly, I'll fix it later, this is the one that doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL can't know ahead of time what types anyone might want to pass in (since it can work with virtually any library), so it takes a generic `const void*` pointer to your raw buffer, and relies on you to describe it accurately with the supplied metadata.

In the case of the [png++ library](http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/), you need to dig a few layers down in the abstraction, as it wraps images, rows and pixels for you.

Since you have a `png::image` instance, `get_pixbuf()` will return you a `png::pixbuf` instance, from which you can get a reference to the first row with `get_row(0)`, which returns a `png::row_traits` specialisation for your pixel type.  This gives you access to the first row of the buffer, at which point you can finally request the raw buffer pointer with the [get_data()](http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/doc/0.2.9/classpng_1_1row__traits_3_01std_1_1vector_3_01pixel_01_4_01_4.html#a91a6fc7e066235eb28f6394bb3e8eddf) method. (This is the first byte of the first row, thus pointing to the start of the contiguous buffer.)

So something like this should do the trick:

```
const void* buffer = image.get_pixbuf().get_row(0).get_data();

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
             0,
             GL_RGBA,
             image.get_width(),
             image.get_height(),
             0,
             GL_ABGR,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             buffer);
```

assuming your image data is 8-bit RGBA, with no row padding.

Comment: std::string pathToPng = "dummy.png";
        png::image<png::gray_pixel> image(pathToPng);
        png::gray_pixel* buffer = image.get_pixbuf().get_row(0).get_data();

../src/a.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
../src/a.cpp:101:65: error: 'png::basic_pixel_buffer<unsigned char, std::vector<unsigned char>, png::row_traits<std::vector<unsigned char> > >::row_type' has no member named 'get_data'
         png::gray_pixel* buffer = image.get_pixbuf().get_row(0).get_data();

Comment: It seems something is not quite right with the line loading.

Comment: GL_ABGR is correct? I can't find it, GL_BGRA is defined tho, but it's another sequence ordering. I am missing a header? (Only working with GLFW and GLEW)

Comment: `GL_ABGR` is defined in the `GL_EXT_abgr` extension, which is universally supported, though you may have to enable it.